# Spring Boot - MongoDB Multiplefield unique

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem like this. The `"name"` and `"lastname"` fields are not unique individually. But name + lastname I want to be unique. So the same "name" can be more than one, or the same "lastname" can be more than one, but I want to have just one "name + lastname".

For example:

Registered in the database:

```
Name: "Erdem" lastName: "ÖZDEMİR"
```

---

```
Name: "Erdem" lastName: "AYDEMİR"
```

When I want to record the above record, I want it to

> record successfully

```
Name: "Ahmet" lastName: "ÖZDEMİR"
```

When I want to record the above record, I want it to

> record successfully

```
Name: "Erdem" lastName: "ÖZDEMİR"
```

But since it's the same name and lastname here,

> ***give me an error***!

How can it be done? How can a solution be created in the entity?
My problem is a little ridiculous, but I need to take care of it.

Contact.java

```
@Document(collection = "contact")
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> phones;

//get & set
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on `name, lastName` then MongoDB will reject any writes which breach that uniqueness.

For example:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": 1, "lastName": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

MongoDB will return a WriteError like this if your unique index is breached:

```
"writeError" : {
      "code" : 11000,
      "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.collection.$a.b_1 dup key: { : null }"
   }
```

Comment: `@CompoundIndex(name = "name_lastName_idx", def = "{'name' : 1, 'lastName' : 1}", unique = true)` ty for helping. i use this annatation create index.